# How to get the total count of Favorite/Favorited authors

Tags: plugins, php, author, count

I'm trying to get the total favorite/Favorited count for each user, i'm planning to add the counts into author.php to show how many authors Favorited him and how many he favorite others, this the plugin code, SO how can i get only the count for each user?

http://wp.ohsikpark.com/favorite-authors/
Description: Favorite Authors allows you to add all of your favorite authors on your account. 
Author: writegnj
Version: 1.2
Author URI: http://www.ohsikpark.com
Text Domain: favorite-authors
License: GPL2
*/
defined( 'ABSPATH' ) or die( 'No script kiddies please!' );

// Define plug-in path
define('FAV_AUTHORS_PATH', plugins_url() . '/favorite-authors');
define('FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY', "favorite-authors");
/*
**  Register CSS & JS assets for plug in
    ------------------------------------------------------------------
*/
// register our form css
function fav_authors_register_assets(){
    wp_register_style( 'favorite-authors', FAV_AUTHORS_PATH . '/favorite-authors.css' );
    wp_register_style( 'themename-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array( 'dashicons' ), '1.0', true );
    wp_register_script( 'favorite-authors-script', FAV_AUTHORS_PATH . '/favorite-authors.js', array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
}
add_action('init', 'fav_authors_register_assets');

// load our form css
function fav_authors_print_assets(){
    global $fav_authors_load_assets;

```
if ( !$fav_authors_load_assets )
    return;

wp_print_styles('favorite-authors');
wp_print_styles('themename-style');
wp_print_scripts('favorite-authors-script');
```

}
add_action('wp_footer', 'fav_authors_print_assets');

// Load and localize JS for AJAX
function fav_authors_enqueue(){
    wp_localize_script( 'favorite-authors-script', 'fav_authors_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ), 'ajax_nonce' => wp_create_nonce('fav_authors_obj_ajax')) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'fav_authors_enqueue' );

// Get curren user
function fav_authors_get_user_id(){
    global $current_user;
    wp_get_current_user();
    return $current_user->ID;
}

// Add favorite authors to current user's usermeta
function fav_author_add_fav_author(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'fav_authors_obj_ajax', 'security' );
    $add_this_author = absint($_POST['clicked_author_id']);

```
if($add_this_author !== (int)$add_this_author)
    return;

if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
    $user_id = absint(fav_authors_get_user_id());

    $author_list = get_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, true );

    if( empty( $author_list ) ) { 
        update_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, array( $add_this_author ) );
    } else {
        $author_arr = ( is_array( $author_list ) ) ? $author_list : array( $author_list );

        if(in_array($add_this_author, $author_list))
            return;

        $author_arr[] = $add_this_author;
        update_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, $author_arr );
    }
}
die();
```

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_fav_author_id', 'fav_author_add_fav_author' );

// Remove favorite authors from current user's usermeta
function fav_author_remove_user(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'fav_authors_obj_ajax', 'security' );

```
if ($_POST['clicked_author_id']){
    $remove_this_author = absint($_POST['clicked_author_id']);

    if($remove_this_author !== (int)$remove_this_author)
        return;

    if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ){
        $user_id = absint(fav_authors_get_user_id());

        $author_list = get_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, true );
        //print_r($author_list);
        $author_saved = array_search($remove_this_author, $author_list);

        if( FALSE !== $author_saved ){
            // Remove $author_saved
            unset($author_list[$author_saved]);
            $author_arr = ( is_array( $author_list ) ) ? $author_list : array( $author_list );
            update_user_meta( $user_id, FAV_AUTHORS_META_KEY, $author_arr );
        }
    }

}
die();
```

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_fav_author_id', 'fav_author_remove_user' );

// Add shorcode on php file
function fav_authors_link(){
    wp_enqueue_style('favorite-authors');

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_enqueue_script('favorite-authors-script');
    wp_enqueue_style('themename-style');

    $fav_author_list = get_user_option( 'favorite-authors', fav_authors_get_user_id() );
    //var_dump( $fav_author_list ); 

    global $post;
    //print_r($post);
    $user_id = absint($post->post_author);

    if(fav_authors_get_user_id() == $user_id)
        return;

    if( empty( $fav_author_list ) ){
        $str = '<span class="fav_authors add-fav" id="fav_author_button" data-author-id="'.$user_id.'"><span class="dashicons dashicons-star-filled"></span> Favorite'; 
    }else{

        if(in_array($user_id, $fav_author_list)){
            $str = '<span class="fav_authors rmv-fav" id="fav_author_rmove_button" data-author-id="'.$user_id.'"><span class="dashicons dashicons-yes"></span> Favorited!';
        }else{
            $str = '<span class="fav_authors add-fav" id="fav_author_button" data-author-id="'.$user_id.'"><span class="dashicons dashicons-star-filled"></span> Favorite';   
        }

    }
    $str .= '</span>';

    echo $str;
}else{
    echo '<p class="fa-signin"><a href="'.wp_login_url().'" title="Login">Log in to favorite this author</a></p>';
}
```

}

/*
**  Pagination for favorite author list by current user
    This pagination code and get favorite user list code can be clearned up better than this...
*/
function fav_authors_pagi(){
    check_ajax_referer( 'fav_authors_obj_ajax', 'security' );
    //var_dump($_POST);
    $fav_author_list = get_user_option( 'favorite-authors', fav_authors_get_user_id() );

```
$page = ! empty( $_POST['clicked_author_id'] ) ? (int) $_POST['clicked_author_id'] : 1;
$total = count( $fav_author_list ); 
$limit = 20; // <----------------------------------------------------- Set number of authors to show per page
$totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit );
$page = max($page, 1);
$page = min($page, $totalPages);
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;


if ($fav_author_list){
    $fav_author_list = array_slice( $fav_author_list, $offset, $limit );

    foreach($fav_author_list as $fav_au ){
        $fa_au = get_userdata( $fav_au );
        $author_url = esc_url(site_url( "/author/" ).$fa_au->user_login);

        echo '<li><a href="'.$author_url.'">';
        echo esc_html($fa_au->display_name);
        echo '</a> <span class="fav_authors rmv-fav" id="fav_author_rmove_button" data-author-id="'.$fa_au->ID.'"><span class="dashicons dashicons-yes"></span> Favorited!</span></li>';
    }
}else{
    echo '<h2>Add favorite authors!</h2>';
}
die();
```

}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fav_au_pagi', 'fav_authors_pagi' );

/*
**  Get favorite author list by current user
    Shortcode [favorite-authors-list] function
*/
function fav_authors_get_list(){
    $fav_author_list = get_user_option( 'favorite-authors', fav_authors_get_user_id() );
    //var_dump( $fav_author_list );

```
$page = ! empty( $_POST['page'] ) ? (int) $_POST['page'] : 1;
$total = count( $fav_author_list );  
$limit = 20; // <----------------------------------------------------- Set number of authors to show per page
$totalPages = ceil( $total/ $limit ); 
$page = max($page, 1); 
$page = min($page, $totalPages);
$offset = ($page - 1) * $limit;
if( $offset < 0 ) $offset = 0;

if ($fav_author_list){
    $fav_author_list = array_slice( $fav_author_list, $offset, $limit );

    echo '<div class="fav_authors-wrap">';
        echo '<p class="fav-total">Total favorited author: '.$total.'</p>';
        echo '<div class="fav-authors-list" id="fav-authors-list">';
        foreach($fav_author_list as $fav_au ){
            $fa_au = get_userdata( $fav_au );
            $author_url = esc_url(site_url( "/?author=" ).$fa_au->ID);

            echo '<li><a href="'.$author_url.'">';
            echo esc_html($fa_au->display_name);
            echo '</a> <span class="fav_authors rmv-fav" id="fav_author_rmove_button" data-author-id="'.$fa_au->ID.'"><span class="dashicons dashicons-yes"></span> Favorited!</span></li>';
        }
        echo '</div>';
        // Pagination
        echo '<div class="fav-authors-pagination">';

        if( $totalPages != 0 && $total >= $limit) {
            for ($i = $page; $i <= $totalPages; $i++) {
                if ($i == 1){
                    echo '<li id="fav_pagi" data-fav-pid="'.$i.'" class="fa_current">'.$i.'</li>';
                }else{
                    echo '<li id="fav_pagi" data-fav-pid="'.$i.'">'.$i.'</li>';
                }
            }
        }                   
        echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';    
}else{
    echo '<h2>Add your first favorite author!</h2>';
}
```

}

/*
**  Add a shortcode for front end form
    [favorite-authors-list]
    https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_shortcode
*/
function fav_authors_list(){
    // Load CSS & JS files
    global $fav_authors_load_assets;
    $fav_authors_load_assets = true;

```
// Show only to logged in users
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $output = fav_authors_get_list();
    return $output;
}else{
    echo '<p class="login-fav_authors">Please <a href="'.wp_login_url().'" title="Login">Login</a> to continue...</p>';
}
```

}
add_shortcode('favorite-authors-list', 'fav_authors_list');

// Add plug in link to setting page
function fav_authors_action_links( $links ){
   $links[] = 'Documentation';
   return $links;
}
add_filter( 'plugin_action_links_' . plugin_basename(**FILE**), 'fav_authors_action_links' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you to show how many author current user favorite others:

Add this to your themes functions.php file

```
<?php
function get_fav_auth_count(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        global $current_user;
        wp_get_current_user();
        $count = size_of(get_user_option('favorite-authors', $current_user->ID));
        echo $count;
    }
}
?>
```

and call it like this `<?php get_fav_auth_count(); ?>`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sabbir, when i call <?php get_fav_auth_count(); ?> into author.php template give me err with 
jquery.magnific-popup-init.js TypeError: "x" is not a function,

Comment: That's not related with this portion of code.

Comment: it working when i change the size_of to count..but anyways your code bring out who's i favorite him and i want to count who is favorited me?